# Conventional name for matrix with named values? C# dataframe

Tags: c#, python, matrix, multidimensional-array, key

I'd like to implement something in C# where I could define a multidimensional array and index accordingly or get a specific value by key. Is there a conventional name for this? Or a package for it?
I've implemented in python, but I did a bunch of method overriding to make it work conventionally. There, usage looks like this:

```
class NamedTicTacToeBoard(VariableMatrix):
    def __init__(self):
        VariableMatrix.__init__(self)
        self.__shape__ = (3, 3)
        self.A1 = X
        self.A2 = O
        self.A3 = X
# and so forth...

board = NamedTicTacToeBoard()
board[0, :]
>> [X, O, X]
board.A1
>> X
```

Thanks for the help

Edit: I'm not actually making a TicTacToe board, it's for a GNC, so I need to do a bunch of matrix algebra, but also reference the states.

Comment: You can try to use a [Dictionnary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: A dictionary would give you name retrieval and index retrieval, but it wouldn't be 2 dimensional, so out of the box it couldn' represent every matrix.

Comment: A simple `new char[3,3]`is not sufficient for your TicTacToe Board ? Beside the integer index, you also want a string-index ?

Comment: @Holger I'm not actually making a TicTacToe board, it's for state-space guidance and control

Comment: But if you don't answer the question, you limit the answerers to C# developers, that speak Python also. Other people cannot understand the question. You want something like in Excel, a grid, that you can access either via row/column index, or via a given name per cell, like a named cell ? You do not describe your actual task or problem, you describe second hand solutions you have for your problem.
Also for Matrix algebra, most often you require high performance.